# Проблема с кодировкой базы данных при переносе на Macbook в MAMP

Tags: php, sql, кодировка, phpmyadmin

**Дано**: есть корректно работающее приложение на PHP с базой данных расположенное на хостинге и на домашнем Windows ПК (Open Server). 
**Задача**: перенести и запустить данное приложение на MacBook_e (OS X). 
**Проблема**: данные из базы не отображаются корректно в приложении (выводит знаки вопроса - ?????)

Установил MAMP, перенес базу данных, загрузил все файлы приложения.

Кодировка UTF-8 прописана в хедере приложения. 
База имеет кодировку utf8_unicide_ci.
Таблицы имеют кодировку utf8_unicide_ci.

Данные НЕ из базы отображаются корректно. Данные из базы - ?????. 
 
Какие пути решения есть?

Comment: в самой базе данные корректны?

Comment: Да, в базе данные корректны.

Comment: Опишите подробнее как переносили базу данных? Как создавался дамп? Имеется ли в нем настройка кодировки соединения?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего в SQL-дампе не устанавливается кодировка соединения. В результате MySQL-сервер ожидает данные в latin1, которые он преобразует utf8, т.е. вы подаете ему на вход данные в utf8, а он пытается осуществить преобразование latin1->utf8. Результат - побитые данные. Для решения проблемы лучше всего открыть SQL-дамп и в начале прописать строку

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Она сообщит серверу, что кодировкой сессии будет utf8 и дополнительных преобразований осуществлять не требуется.